# CSS Decrease negative margin proportional to viewport width

Tags: css

We have been provided a 1500px wide image that is a mockup of a website.

The website design is a fixed width design, where the design takes up the middle 990px of the image.  So the 255px on either side of the image is just overhang to show how the site would expand to bigger viewports (ie, it wouldn't aside from some edge elements expanding to infinity).

What I would like to do is simulate this with the image (up as far as it will go).  So if the viewport is 1500px, the image would start at 0,0.

If the viewport was 990px or less the image would start at 0,255px.

Anything in between would scale.  So I would like to scale a negative margin from -255 to 0 depending on the width of the viewport.

Kind of like the opposite of

```
margin: 0 -10% 0 0;
```

This goes in the opposite direction to what I am thinking - as the viewport gets wider, the image migrates to the left instead of to the right.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet you could try using some responsive design techniques,..

```
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
    #yourContainer{margin-left:0;background-color:#afa;}

}

@media screen and (max-width:990px){
    #yourContainer{margin-left:255px;background-color:#aaf;}

}
```

background color added for testing only ;)
This jsFiddle demonstrates this, just resize the browser window or the fiddle column width - http://jsfiddle.net/vs6uz/1/

Comment: Yeah, I could do a series of jumps like in the fiddle.  I was hoping for something simpler, a one liner!